# Refactor to remove goto

Tags: c++, strings

Is it possible to implement this function without `goto`, while keeping the code correct and readable?

```
using iter = std::string::const_iterator;

// Skip multiline comment in a source string.
// Initial iterator is at the first character after the "/*"
iter skipMultilineComment( iter i, iter fileEnd )
{
    while( true )
    {
        const char c1 = *i;
        if( c1 != '*' )
        {
            i++;
            if( i != fileEnd )
                continue;
            break;
        }

        // Found '*' character
    FoundAsterisk:
        i++;
        if( i == fileEnd )
            break;
        const char c2 = *i;
        if( c2 == '*' )
        {
/* Found another '*' character; can be more: ****/
            goto FoundAsterisk;
        }
        if( c2 != '/' )
        {
            i++;
            if( i != fileEnd )
                continue;
            break;
        }
        // Finally, found the closing token, "*/"
        i++;
        return i;
    }
    logError( "fatal error C1071: unexpected end of file found in comment" );
    throw E_INVALIDARG;
}
```

P.S. That’s not a test assignment or something, it’s production code. The input is [GLSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language), but the comments there are the same as in C++.

Comment: `[That’s] production code.` [Are you a maintainer of this code?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @greybeard Yep, sole maintainer ATM.

Comment: `Is it possible to implement this function without goto`: There was a famous paper in the 60s => **"BÖhm, Corrado, and Jacopini Guiseppe. Flow diagrams, Turing machines and languages with only two formation rules. Comm. ACM 9 (May 1966), 366-371"**. I believe that showed that higher level concepts could replace all usages of goto. Can't find a link to the paper but it is mentioned in [Dijkstra paper](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html) about goto being harmful later in the 60s.

Comment: In this case I don't think it is that difficult to work out how to replace this goto with a loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, of course. (It's always *possible* to eliminate unstructured constructs by use of structured programming.) I recommend Kernighan & Plauger's *The Elements of Programming Style* for developing your own sense of structured programming.

Come on this journey with me!

Step 1: That confusing `if` at the top of the loop.

```
while (true) {
    const char c1 = *i;
    if( c1 != '*' )
    {
        i++;
        if( i != fileEnd )
            continue;
        break;
    }
```

`c1` is never used again, so we can eliminate it. Then, `break`ing the loop means going to the end of the loop and setting a "don't do this loop again" flag; so let's make that flag; we'll call it `done`. Then `continue`ing the loop means going to the end *without* setting that flag. So at this point we have

```
template<class It>
It skipMultilineComment(It it, It fileEnd)
{
    bool done = false;
    while (!done) {
        if (*it != '*') {
            ++it;
            done = (it == fileEnd);
        } else {
            // Found '*' character
        FoundAsterisk:
            ++it;
            if (it == fileEnd) break;
            if (*it == '*') {
                /* Found another '*' character; can be more: ****/
                goto FoundAsterisk;
            } else if (*it != '/') {
                ++it;
                if (it != fileEnd) continue;
                break;
            }
            // Finally, found the closing token, "*/"
            ++it;
            return it;
        }
    }
    logError( "fatal error C1071: unexpected end of file found in comment" );
    throw E_INVALIDARG;
}
```

Notice that I've cleaned up some whitespace style and renamed `i` (traditionally a name for an integer loop control variable) to `it` (traditionally a name for an iterator). I've also made the function a template so that I can get rid of that global-scope `typedef` at the top.

Okay, let's pull out the next `break`... or, no, let's skip down to that similar `continue/break` tangle at the bottom of the loop, and sort that out. Same transformation as before. I'll just show the loop, because nothing outside it has changed.

```
    while (!done) {
        if (*it != '*') {
            ++it;
            done = (it == fileEnd);
        } else {
            // Found '*' character
        FoundAsterisk:
            ++it;
            if (it == fileEnd) break;
            if (*it == '*') {
                /* Found another '*' character; can be more: ****/
                goto FoundAsterisk;
            } else if (*it == '/') {
                // Finally found the closing token, "*/"
                ++it;
                return it;
            } else {
                ++it;
                done = (it == fileEnd);
            }
        }
    }
```

Notice that I am also habitually untangling your `if/else` blocks. You don't want to have `if (a == x) ... else if (a != y) ... else if (a == z) ...` because that's just plain confusing. `if/else` chains should read like switch statements: one handler per interesting value. So here we have one handler for `*it == '*'`, and one handler for `*it == '/'`, and then one catch-all "else" handler.

Let's follow that guideline and refactor the outer `if (*it != '*')` as well.
Notice that once we do that, we don't need the comment `// Found '*' character` anymore, because it's obvious from the code itself. Getting to remove pointless comments is one of the most satisfying parts of the refactoring process!

```
    while (!done) {
        if (*it == '*') {
        FoundAsterisk:
            ++it;
            if (it == fileEnd) {
                done = true;
            } else if (*it == '*') {
                goto FoundAsterisk;
            } else if (*it == '/') {
                // Finally found the closing token, "*/"
                ++it;
                return it;
            } else {
                ++it;
                done = (it == fileEnd);
            }
        } else {
            ++it;
            done = (it == fileEnd);
        }
    }
```

Okay, let's tackle that `goto`. The fundamental algorithm here is, "While we're looking at a `*` character, increment `it`. But if we reach the end of the string, then stop." Normally we'd spell that as

```
while (it != fileEnd && *it == '*') { ++it; }
```

Let's see if we can shoehorn that line of code into our function in a natural way.

```
    while (!done) {
        if (*it == '*') {
            while (it != fileEnd && *it == '*') {
                ++it;
            }
            if (it == fileEnd) {
                done = true;
            } else if (*it == '/') {
                // Finally found the closing token, "*/"
                ++it;
                return it;
            } else {
                ++it;
                done = (it == fileEnd);
            }
        } else {
            ++it;
            done = (it == fileEnd);
        }
    }
```

Notice that every path to the bottom of the outer loop now ends with `done = (it == fileEnd)` (except in one case where we already know `it == fileEnd` and so we just set `done = true`). So basically we just keep going until `it == fileEnd`. That's our loop condition.

```
    while (it != fileEnd) {
        if (*it == '*') {
            while (it != fileEnd && *it == '*') {
                ++it;
            }
            if (it == fileEnd) {
            } else if (*it == '/') {
                // Finally found the closing token, "*/"
                ++it;
                return it;
            } else {
                ++it;
            }
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
```

Okay, but, now we've got a loop *within* a loop. You know what? Maybe what we really want here is a simple state machine: Either we've just seen a `*`, or we haven't. If we have, and the next character is `/`, then we're done. Otherwise, keep going. That would code up like this:

```
template<class It>
It skipMultilineComment(It it, It fileEnd)
{
    for (bool seenStar = false; it != fileEnd; ++it) {
        if (*it == '/' && seenStar) {
            return it + 1;
        }
        seenStar = (*it == '*');
    }
    logError( "fatal error C1071: unexpected end of file found in comment" );
    throw E_INVALIDARG;
}
```

Yes. I like that better. But wait, we can do better than that! All we seem to be doing is looking for the string `"*/"` inside a longer string. That's *string search*, and there are library functions for that!

```
#include <string.h>

const char *skipMultilineComment(const char *it, const char *fileEnd)
{
    if (const char *p = memmem(it, fileEnd - it, "*/", 2)) {
        return p + 2;
    }
    logError( "fatal error C1071: unexpected end of file found in comment" );
    throw E_INVALIDARG;
}
```

or in C++17,

```
std::string_view skipMultilineComment(std::string_view text)
{
    size_t pos = text.find("*/");
    if (pos != text.npos) {
        return text.substr(pos + 2);
    }
    logError( "fatal error C1071: unexpected end of file found in comment" );
    throw E_INVALIDARG;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The string_view approach was just what I needed. I do have C++/17, the software I’m working on is only built by VC++ 2017 (AMD64) and GCC 8.3 (ARMv7).

Comment: BTW, string literal would probably work slightly better for the search string, i.e. `"*/"s` instead of just `"*/"`. AFAIK compilers aren’t that smart, they don’t precompute `strlen` even for very small constexpr strings.

Comment: @Soonts: Nope, I wrote what I meant. Try it in Godbolt and see! (The compiler knows how many characters are in `"*/"`. The compiler is the one who _put_ them there.)

Comment: I have put it in Godbolt, and seeing a function call to `__gnu_cxx::char_traits<char>::length(char const*)`. Now,  `-O2` switch helps, but no reason to slow down debug builds, it’s just 1 extra character in the source code.